# Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SampleMethod' in DLL 'goDLL.dll'

Tags: c#, go

I'm trying to call a golang dll from c#, and comparing the results and performance against calling c dll from c#, so I did the below:

I started with building the c dll and calling it
step 1: Writting the c code

```c
// cmdll.c
// Compile with: -LD
int __declspec(dllexport) SampleMethod(int i)
{
  return i*10;
}
```

step 2: Compiling the c code:

- Open the `Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`
- Run the command: `cl -LD cmdll.c`

step 3: Writting the c# code

```cs
// cm.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MainClass
{
    [DllImport("Cmdll.dll")]
    public static extern int SampleMethod(int x); // function signature, must have a return type

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod() returns {0}.", SamplMethod(5));
    }
}
```

step 4: Compile the c# file and build the exe as:

- Open the `Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`
- Run the command: `csc -platform:x64 cm.cs`

The things above run smoothly

I wanted to do the same using golang, and followed the below:

step 1: Write the go code:

```golang
//lib.go
package main

import "C"

//export SamplMethod
func SamplMethod(i int) int {
    return i * 10
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

step 2: Build the dll file, by compiling the above code as:

```bash
go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o lib.dll -buildmode=c-shared lib.go
```

I used the `-ldflags="-s -w"` to reduce the resulting file size, and not sure what `-buildmode` shall i use, so randomly selected `c-shared` instead of `c-archive`
update: I tried also with `go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o lib.dll -buildmode=c-archive lib.go` and got the same result

step 3: Write a c code that combine the `.dll` and `.h` file generated from the `go` to generate an equivalent `c dll`

```c
//goDll.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"
// force gcc to link in go runtime (may be a better solution than this)
GoInt SamplMethod(GoInt i);

void main() {
}
```

step 4: Compile the goDll.c file as:

```bash
gcc -shared -pthread -o goDll.dll goDll.c lib.dll -lWinMM -lntdll -lWS2_32
```

step 5: Build the c# code to call the generated dll, same code as above, but changing the dll file name:

```cs
// cm.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MainClass
{
    [DllImport("goDll.dll")]
    public static extern int SampleMethod(int x); // function signature, must have a return type

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod() returns {0}.", SamplMethod(5));
    }
}
```

step 4: Compile the c# file and build the exe as:

- Open the `Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`
- Run the command: `csc -platform:x64 cm.cs`

Then tried to run the generated `./cm.exe` file, but got the below error:

```bash
Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SampleMethod' in DLL 'goDll.dll'.
   at MainClass.SampleMethod(Int32 i)
   at MainClass.Main()
```

Comment: Just in case: in the provided Go code snippet you have a type: the name of the function is SamplMethod instead of SampleMethod.Maybe this is the cause of the error?

Comment: You don't need to compile cgo.dll. lib.dll is enough. Link your c# application against it directly

Comment: Thanks @PakUula, this hist really solved my issue and saved my time, I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Pak Uula comment, it worked with me as below:

step 1: Write the go code:

```golang
// main.go
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world from GO\n")
}

func main() {}

// compile the code as:
// go build -ldflags="-s -w" -buildmode=c-shared -o libgo.dll main.go
```

step 2: Write the c# code as:

```cs
// main.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MainClass
{
    [DllImport("libgo.dll")]
    public static extern void HelloWorld(); // function signature, must have a return type

    static void Main()
    {
        HelloWorld();
    }
}

// compile as:
// open:
// Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
// csc -platform:x64 cm.cs
```

step 3: Compile both files, start by compiling the `go` file

step 4: Run the executable file:

[image]

**UPDATE**

1. Go file:

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// The import "C" should come directly after the // #include ..., i.e. no empty lines allowed,
// if there are empty lines, the compliler will read the // #include as normal comment, not as C import

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

//export GetHello
func GetHello(Input *C.char) *C.char {
    cStr := C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("From DLL: Hello, %s!\n", C.GoString(Input)))
    //  C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStr))
    return cStr
}

func main() {}

// compile the code as:
// go build -ldflags="-s -w" -buildmode=c-shared -o libgo.dll main.go
```

2. C# file:

```cs
// main.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MainClass
{
    [DllImport("libgo.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetHello(byte[] data);

    static string CallDll(string name) {
        IntPtr output= IntPtr.Zero;
        var a = GetHello(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name));

        return "GetHello Returns: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(a);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CallDll("Ahmad"));
    }
}

// compile as:
// open:
// Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Command Prompt
// csc -platform:x64 main.cs
```

Here is an example that is working with string:

[image]